# Why does he first <hr /> Element in a list doesn't show up bot the others do using React Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

**The Problem**

I have a simple List of components that renders a title and an simple `<hr />` after it. 
The list gets rendered correctly and every title has it's corresponding `<hr />` **except the first one**

Here is a screenshot how it looks:

[image]

I don't have any custom styles in my project except this one (for a rich text editor called `Draft.js`:

```
.editor {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: text;
  padding: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 8px -3px #ababab;
  background: #fefefe;
}

.editor :global(.public-DraftEditor-content) {
  min-height: 140px;
}
```

Other then that, no css files.

Here is the code that renders the list (it gets called in the parent for every list item I have):

```
return (
<div>
  <h2>{props.title}</h2>
  <p>Test</p>
  <hr />
  {renderPosts()}
</div>
```

);

Why is this happening? I played around with it in the dev tools and the missing`<hr />` is actually there, but not visible but the styling seems ok. It makes no sense to me because the other hr's are there. Screenshot from the Dev Tools:

[image]

Comment: could you put the code in a fiddle so we can reproduce it ? Probably one of the other elements is overlapping your hr

Comment: Hi, thank you for you help. I have a github repo, is this good enough? https://github.com/dhuber666/MyHouse "Editor" Branch

Comment: @Gonzalo.- I created a very simple version on codesandbox.  https://codesandbox.io/s/54m113kmqx
Here it's working as intended

Comment: If I change the styling in the dev tools to a `border-bottom` of `2px solid #eee` instead of 1px, all borders thatt where already visible get "thicker" and the "not showing" border gets visible with like 1px. I don't get it

Comment: that probably means that one element is over that hr by one pixel. Inspect all the elements to see which one overlaps

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. 
It's another Bootstrap Component that overlapped the first element like @Gonzalo said.
This was the faulty code from the parent component:

```
return (
  <div style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
    {/* TODO: implement AddRoom Component */}

    {/* <OverlayTrigger
      trigger="focus"
      placement="top"
      overlay={this.popoverTop()}
    >
      <Button>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
      </Button>
    </OverlayTrigger> */}

    {this.renderRooms()}
  </div>
);
```

I uncommented it and now I see the `<hr />` I think now I have to give the `OverlayTrigger` just a bit margin and I'm guchi.